# What does Java object assignment mean?

Tags: java, object, variable-assignment

I have the following 2 classes :

```
class Animal {
    public static void staticMethod(int i) {
        System.out.println("Animal : static -- " + i);
    }

    public void instanceMethod(int i) {
        System.out.println("Animal : instance -- " + i);
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    public static void staticMethod(int i) {
        System.out.println("Cat : static -- " + i);
    }

    public void instanceMethod(int i) {
        System.out.println("Cat : instance -- " + i);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat myCat = new Cat();
        myCat.staticMethod(1);                       // Cat : static -- 1
        myCat.instanceMethod(2);                     // Cat : instance -- 2
        System.out.println("");

        Animal myAnimal = myCat;
        Animal.staticMethod(3);                      // Animal : static -- 3 
        myAnimal.staticMethod(4);                    // Animal : static -- 4 [ ? ]
        System.out.println("");

        myAnimal.instanceMethod(5);                  // Cat : instance -- 5
    }
}
```

And when I run Cat, I got the following results :

```
Cat : static -- 1
Cat : instance -- 2

Animal : static -- 3
Animal : static -- 4

Cat : instance -- 5
```

I can understand 1,2,3 and 5, but why #4 is not : " Cat : static -- 4 " ?
My understanding would be like this :

myAnimal=myCat means "myAnimal" is now exactly the same as "myCat", so anywhere "myAnimal" apears, you can replace it with "myCat" and get the same result, because everything inside myAnimal is the same as everything inside myCat, therefore "myAnimal.staticMethod(4)" should be the same as "myCat.staticMethod(4)" and the output should be : "Cat : static -- 4", similiar to "myCat.staticMethod(1)" above.

But that doesn't seem to be the case, why ?

Comment: Here is the eclipse telling me: `The static method staticMethod(int) from the type Animal should be accessed in a static way` since it is a static method then it is only bounded to the parent when you call its obj which is `Animal`.

Comment: statics are linked at compile time. That's what prevent them from being overriden

Comment: Its a duplicate question asked around manytimes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8):

> **8.4.8.2. Hiding (by Class Methods)**
>
> If a class C declares or inherits a static method m, then m is said to
>   hide any method m', where the signature of m is a subsignature
>   (§8.4.2) of the signature of m', in the superclasses and
>   superinterfaces of C that would otherwise be accessible to code in C.
>
> Example 8.4.8.2-1. Invocation of Hidden Class Methods
>
> A class (static) method that is hidden can be invoked by using a
>   reference whose type is the class that actually contains the
>   declaration of the method. In this respect, hiding of static methods
>   is different from overriding of instance methods. The example:

```
class Super {
            static String greeting() { return "Goodnight"; }
            String name() { return "Richard"; }
        }
        class Sub extends Super {
            static String greeting() { return "Hello"; }
            String name() { return "Dick"; }
        }
        class Test {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                Super s = new Sub();
                System.out.println(s.greeting() + ", " + s.name());
            }
        }
```

> produces the output:
>
> Goodnight, Dick
>
> because the invocation of greeting uses the type of s, namely Super,
>   to figure out, at compile time, which class method to invoke, whereas
>   the invocation of name uses the class of s, namely Sub, to figure out,
>   at run time, which instance method to invoke.

Answer (score 3):

You declare `myAnimal` as `Animal`. Therefore a static method is called from that class too.

You should never call static methods (or access static fields) from an instance to prevent this kind of confusion.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that Java resolves static methods based on the type of the reference variable itself, and not polymorphically at run time, as happens with instance methods.

To expand a little bit, when you are doing `Animal myAnimal = myCat`, you are assigning a Cat reference to an Animal reference. This is acceptable, because a `Cat` is also an `Animal`, so anything that an `Animal` can do, a `Cat` can do also.

Furthermore, if you call an instance (that is, non static) method via the `myAnimal` reference, and the method is overriden in `Cat`, then the `Cat` version of the method is called, because that's why the method was overriden in the first place. Static methods, on the other hand, are never overriden. That's why they are "static", as in "non-dynamic". Meaning that static methods can be resolved by the compiler instead of having to rely on the runtime environment.

Answer (score 1):

**Static** means exactly that: the call is resolved statically (in your case, it is resolved based on the declared type of the *variable*, and the variable is a compile-time entity).

The result you expected would require that the call is resolved **dynamically** (polymorphically, based on the actual type of the referenced instance, and the instance is a runtime entity).

Answer (score 1):

When you set myAnimal = myCat, the pointer myAnimal points to a cat object, but when you try to access the static method through the myAnimal pointer it accesses the static method from the class that myAnimal was declared as.